# What Are the Differences for test -p /dev/fd/0 and test ! -t 0

Tags: linux, pipe, tty

Actually I can see two differences on the effects level but I'm curios what are they stand for behind the system?

First `-t` is sensitive both for piping and redirects from files while `-p` only for piping

```sh
: | (test -p /dev/fd/0  &&  echo 1 || echo 0)             # produces 1
(test -p /dev/fd/0  &&  echo 1 || echo 0) < some_source   # produces 0

: | (test ! -t 0  &&  echo 1 || echo 0)                   # produces 1
(test ! -t 0  &&  echo 1 || echo 0) < some_source         # produces 1
```

According to man

```
-p file       True if file is a named pipe (FIFO).
```

So isn't redirect from file identical to `cat |` approach?

And the second is why closing an stdin affects these criterion in different ways?

```sh
: | (0<&- test -p /dev/fd/0  &&  echo 1 || echo 0)         # produces 0
: | (0<&- test ! -t 0  &&  echo 1 || echo 0)               # produces 1
```

Comment: Named pipes and TTYs are different things. Are you asking us to explain the difference between them?

Comment: I'm actually surprised that `/dev/fd/0` registers as a named pipe.